# quereies related to autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, encoding

i want to  design an deep auto encoder after following keras tutorial.

Input is a simple 2-dimensional image consists of 512 rows and 50 columns matrix

My trial code is

```
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
```

i have some queries I need to clarify.
In the above code what is the size of the latent space.Is it 32 dimension.But my image is 2dimensional then how the information is compressed, can anybody clarify it.

b) does the latent space size is always = number of neurons of last encoder layer(i.e. 32)